# Filtering the XML Node binded with dropdownlist

Tags: xslt, xpath, filtering, xmldatasource

I have two DropDownList: 1) CollegeDDL which contains Four static names of the colleges. : Homeopathic Medical College,Physiotherapy College,Institute of Ayurveda,Institute of Business Administration

2) CourseDDL which is bind to CourseDetail.XML.

```
    <Institutes>  
    <Institute>
    <InstituteName>  Homoeopathic Medical College  </InstituteName>
    <Course> <CourseName>  BHMS                    </CourseName> </Course>  
    <Course> <CourseName>  MD(Repertary)           </CourseName> </Course>  
    <Course> <CourseName>  MD(Organon of Medicine) </CourseName> </Course>  
    <Course> <CourseName>  MD(Materia Medica)      </CourseName> </Course>  
    </Institute>

    <Institute>
    <InstituteName>  Physiotherapy College  </InstituteName>
    <Course> <CourseName>  BPT          </CourseName> </Course> 
    <Course> <CourseName>  BPT(Sports)  </CourseName> </Course> 
    <Course> <CourseName>  BPT(Cardio)  </CourseName> </Course>
    </Institute>

    <Institute>
    <InstituteName>  Institute of Ayurved  </InstituteName>
    <Course> <CourseName>  BAMS          </CourseName> </Course>
    <Course> <CourseName>  BAMS(Nature)  </CourseName> </Course>
    <Course> <CourseName>  BAMS(Plants)  </CourseName> </Course>
    </Institute>

    <Institute>
    <InstituteName> Institute of Business Administration </InstituteName>
    <Course> <CourseName>BBA</CourseName> </Course> 
    <Course> <CourseName>DBM</CourseName> </Course> 
    <Course> <CourseName>BBA(Distance)</CourseName> </Course>   
    </Institute>
```

---

CourseDetail.XSL

```
    <xsl:template match ="/">

    <Institute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="Institutes/Institute/Course"/>
    </Institute>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match ="Institutes/Institute/Course">
    <Institute>
    <xsl:attribute name="CourseName">
    <xsl:value-of select="CourseName"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </Institute>

    </xsl:template>
```

I have bind Coursedetail.XML to CourseDDL and CourseDetail.XSL (No XPATH Expression)

After doing this, My CourseDDL is correctly filled with all the CourseName value of my XML file.
But now I want to filter the data bound to CourseDDL , based on College Name selected in CollegeDDL.

For Example:Currently my CourseDDL contains all the CourseName : BHMS,MD(Repertary),MD(Organon of Medicine),......,DBM,BBA(Distance).

But when I select "Homoeopathic Medical College" in CollegeDDL , The data bound to CourseDDL should filter accordingly.
It means when I select "Homoeopathic Medical College" , my CourseDDL should Display only that course: BHMS,MD(Repertary),MD(Organon of Medicine),MD(Materia Medica)

---

I have tried the following , but could not achieve it.

```
    1) XmlDataSourceCourse.XPath = "/Institutes/Institute[InstituteName='" +         CollegeDDL.SelectedItem.Value + "']"

    2) XmlDataSourceCourse.XPath = "/Institutes/Institute[InstituteName='" +         CollegeDDL.SelectedItem.Value + "']/Course"

    3)XmlDataSourceCourse.XPath = "/Institutes/Institute[InstituteName='" + CollegeDDL.SelectedItem.Value + "']/Course/CourseName"
```

Anybody please help to format correct XPATH Expression to achive this.

Comment: maybe it's the spaces? did you try `/Institutes/Institute[normalize-space(InstituteName)='<your value goes here>']`

Answer (score 0):

I think that Pavel is right, the problems are the spaces - try:

```
/Institutes/Institute[normalize-space(InstituteName)='" + CollegeDDL.SelectedItem.Value + "']/Course/CourseName
```

or even

```
/Institutes/Institute[normalize-space(InstituteName)=normalize-space('" + CollegeDDL.SelectedItem.Value + "')]/Course/CourseName
```